# D3.js parsing error when trying to generate a node tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Google Chrome console is returning the following error:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M296.20961279999995,NaNC462.51521919999993,NaN 311.0200934399999,NaN 477.3256998399999,NaN"
```

Posted is my code:

```
var taskflows = [ 
{
"description" : "Taskflow #1",
"taskExecutions" : [
    {"description" : "First","step" : 1},
    {"description" : "Second","step" : 2},
    {"description" : "Second", "step" : 2},
    {"description" : "Third", "step" : 3},
    {"description" : "Fourth", "step" : 4},
    {"description" : "Fifth","step" : 5}, 
    {"description" : "Sixth", "step" : 6},
    {"description" : "Sixth", "step" : 6},
    {"description" : "Seventh","step" : 7},
    {"description" : "Eighth", "step" : 8},
    {"description" : "Ninth", "step" : 9},
    {"description" : "Tenth", "step" : 10},
    {"description" : "Eleventh", "step" : 11},
    {"description" : "Twelve", "step" : 12},
    {"description" : "Twelve","step" : 12}
    ]
}];

var taskflowTree = function (taskflow) {
    var tree = taskflow.map(function(a) {
      return { "name": a.description, "step": a.step }
    });

    tree.forEach(function(v, i, arr) {
      v.children = arr.filter(function(a) {
        return a.step == v.step+1;
      });
    });

    return tree.filter(function(a) {
      return a.step == 1;
    });
}


var formattedTaskflowTree = taskflowTree(taskflows[0].taskExecutions);

(function(treeData) {

        // Calculate total nodes, max label length
        var totalNodes = 0;
        var maxLabelLength = 0;
        // variables for drag/drop
        var selectedNode = null;
        var draggingNode = null;
        // panning variables
        var panSpeed = 200;
        var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
        // Misc. variables
        var i = 0;
        var duration = 750;
        var root;

        // size of the diagram
        var viewerWidth = $(document).width();
        var viewerHeight = $(document).height();

        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
            .size([viewerHeight, viewerWidth]);

        // define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
            .projection(function(d) {
                return [d.y, d.x];
            });

        // A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all nodes

        function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
            if (!parent) return;

            visitFn(parent);

            var children = childrenFn(parent);
            if (children) {
                var count = children.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
                }
            }
        }

        // Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
        visit(treeData, function(d) {
            totalNodes++;
            maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);

        }, function(d) {
            return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
        });


        // sort the tree according to the node names

        function sortTree() {
            tree.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
            });
        }
        // Sort the tree initially incase the JSON isn't in a sorted order.
        sortTree();

        // TODO: Pan function, can be better implemented.

        function pan(domNode, direction) {
            var speed = panSpeed;
            if (panTimer) {
                clearTimeout(panTimer);
                translateCoords = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform"));
                if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
                    translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0] - speed;
                    translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
                } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
                    translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
                    translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1] - speed;
                }
                scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
                scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
                scale = zoomListener.scale();
                svgGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
                d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
                zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
                zoomListener.translate([translateX, translateY]);
                panTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                    pan(domNode, speed, direction);
                }, 50);
            }
        }

        // Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree

        function zoom() {
            svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        }


        // define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
        var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.1, 3]).on("zoom", zoom);

        function initiateDrag(d, domNode) {
            draggingNode = d;
            d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', 'none');
            d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle show');
            d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node activeDrag');

            svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").sort(function(a, b) { // select the parent and sort the path's
                if (a.id != draggingNode.id) return 1; // a is not the hovered element, send "a" to the back
                else return -1; // a is the hovered element, bring "a" to the front
            });
            // if nodes has children, remove the links and nodes
            if (nodes.length > 1) {
                // remove link paths
                links = tree.links(nodes);
                nodePaths = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function(d) {
                        return d.target.id;
                    }).remove();
                // remove child nodes
                nodesExit = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function(d) {
                        return d.id;
                    }).filter(function(d, i) {
                        if (d.id == draggingNode.id) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }).remove();
            }

            // remove parent link
            parentLink = tree.links(tree.nodes(draggingNode.parent));
            svgGroup.selectAll('path.link').filter(function(d, i) {
                if (d.target.id == draggingNode.id) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }).remove();

            dragStarted = null;
        }


        // define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
        var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
            .attr("width", viewerWidth)
            .attr("height", viewerHeight)
            .attr("class", "overlay")
            .call(zoomListener);

      // Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        function expand(d) {
            if (d._children) {
                d.children = d._children;
                d.children.forEach(expand);
                d._children = null;
            }
        }

        var overCircle = function(d) {
            selectedNode = d;
            updateTempConnector();
        };
        var outCircle = function(d) {
            selectedNode = null;
            updateTempConnector();
        };

        // Function to update the temporary connector indicating dragging affiliation
        var updateTempConnector = function() {
            var data = [];
            if (draggingNode !== null && selectedNode !== null) {
                // have to flip the source coordinates since we did this for the existing connectors on the original tree
                data = [{
                    source: {
                        x: selectedNode.y0,
                        y: selectedNode.x0
                    },
                    target: {
                        x: draggingNode.y0,
                        y: draggingNode.x0
                    }
                }];
            }
            var link = svgGroup.selectAll(".templink").data(data);

            link.enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "templink")
                .attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal())
                .attr('pointer-events', 'none');

            link.attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal());

            link.exit().remove();
        };

        // Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of children.

        function centerNode(source) {
            scale = zoomListener.scale();
            x = -source.y0;
            y = -source.x0;
            x = x * scale + viewerWidth / 2;
            y = y * scale + viewerHeight / 2;
            d3.select('g').transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
            zoomListener.scale(scale);
            zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
        }

        // Toggle children function

        function toggleChildren(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else if (d._children) {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            return d;
        }

        // Toggle children on click.

        function click(d) {
            if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
            d = toggleChildren(d);
            update(d);
            centerNode(d);
        }

        function update(source) {
            // Compute the new height, function counts total children of root node and sets tree height accordingly.
            // This prevents the layout looking squashed when new nodes are made visible or looking sparse when nodes are removed
            // This makes the layout more consistent.
            var levelWidth = [1];
            var childCount = function(level, n) {

                if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
                    if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

                    levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
                    n.children.forEach(function(d) {
                        childCount(level + 1, d);
                    });
                }
            };
            childCount(0, root);
            var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25; // 25 pixels per line  
            tree = tree.size([newHeight, viewerWidth]);

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                links = tree.links(nodes);

            // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 10)); //maxLabelLength * 10px
                // alternatively to keep a fixed scale one can set a fixed depth per level
                // Normalize for fixed-depth by commenting out below line
                // d.y = (d.depth * 500); //500px per level.
            });

            // Update the nodes…
            node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
                .data(nodes, function(d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                .call(dragListener)
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                })
                .on('click', click);

            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr('class', 'nodeCircle')
                .attr("r", 0)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            nodeEnter.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr('class', 'nodeText')
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                })
                .style("fill-opacity", 0);

            // phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
                .attr("r", 30)
                .attr("opacity", 0.2) // change this to zero to hide the target area
            .style("fill", "red")
                .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
                .on("mouseover", function(node) {
                    overCircle(node);
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(node) {
                    outCircle(node);
                });

            // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
            node.select('text')
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                    return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                });

            // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
            node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
                .attr("r", 4.5)
                .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                });

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

            // Fade the text in
            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                })
                .remove();

            nodeExit.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 0);

            nodeExit.select("text")
                .style("fill-opacity", 0);

            // Update the links…
            var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
                .data(links, function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                });

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x0,
                        y: source.y0
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", diagonal);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    var o = {
                        x: source.x,
                        y: source.y
                    };
                    return diagonal({
                        source: o,
                        target: o
                    });
                })
                .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function(d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }

        // Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom Listener can act upon.
        var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g");

        // Define the root
        root = treeData;
        root.x0 = viewerHeight / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        // Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
        update(root);
        centerNode(root);
    })(formattedTaskflowTree[0]);
```

Posted is a screenshot of the re-occurring errors that I'm receiving upon loading up the tree.

[image]

Comment: Could you narrow it down to a minimal example please?

Comment: I'm not sure which section of the D3.js function is causing the error so I posted the entire thing. Any advice on how to minimize the example to only what's relevant? The error didn't give me much feedback other than it's occurring at d3.js:8473. However, d3.js isn't part of my code. It's the D3.js library that I'm including.

Comment: Well you have a lot of code in there that takes care of panning and dragging for example, I assume that this is not relevant?

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip. I just removed it.

Comment: I get a new error though when removing it. "Uncaught ReferenceError: dragListener is not defined"

Comment: The idea is that we don't have to look through heaps of unrelated code to find the error. You're much more likely to get a reply here if you have a small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Completely agree. I just wish I knew which portions of the code are irrelevant.

Comment: A tip for tracking down errors in Chrome: if you click on the triangle next to the error message, it will print the stack trace, showing the sequence of function calls that led up to the error.  That way you can trace the problem back to the correct line of your original code.
More specifically, the error you're getting shows `NaN` values for all the Y-coordinates in your path, so you've got a problem with your Y scale or with the d.y values.  Is the error happening on initial drawing or after panning/zooming/etc?

Comment: The error happens on initial drawing. I clicked the triangle and it traces back to line 8470 of d3.js which is the section of code that covers function attrTween. Not sure how this relates to any line(s) in my original code...