# Using a variable instead of an external file for d3 script

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Am really way out of my comfort zone here - trying to get a representation of a tree using Mike Bostocks collapsible tree. (original on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

I have the code working, and referencing to my own json data file works, but I need the data in a variable instead of an external file. (due to limitations of the platform I'm using the visualisation on).

The following code calls a file called *Objecttree.json*, and I want to replace this with a similarly named variable called *Objecttree*.

It must be deadsimple, but I've searched the existing answers and am not able to use the answers given in my code. I guess skills are even below the lowest noob-threshold, so please keep that in mind!

anyway, thanks in advance.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 3000 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("Objecttree.json", function(error, flare) {
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Comment: just remove the call to `d3.json`, move the callback body to the main code and replace `root = flare` by `root = Objecttree`..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517967/using-d3-js-with-a-javascript-object-instead-of-an-external-json-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639305/d3js-take-data-from-an-array-instead-of-a-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764698/loading-d3-js-data-from-a-simple-json-string or ...

Comment: Thanks @PauloScardine, I think I almost have that working. The callback body, is that everything from "root = flare" up to and including " update(root);"? - if so I am missing something because that doesn;t seem to work yet. Have I mentioned i'm in way over my head wioth this code? Thanks for all your patience anyway..

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, I actually found all those, but I'm not able to trabnslate that to my code, I'm probably missing something small and semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var Objecttree = '{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.06690766172651032,0.060532461291637356],"translate":[-7.240804475075604,51.182450466981884]},"objects":{"outerLine":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"LineString","arcs":[0,1]},{"type":"LineString","arcs":[2,1]}]}},"arcs":[[[0,269],[41,82]],[[41,351],[115,70],[68,10],[35,3],[26,1],[11,-4]],[[295,429],[99,-39],[59,-48],[8,-82],[-34,-91],[-39,-84],[-63,-74],[-54,-11],[-54,12],[-41,8],[-103,82],[-56,66],[-10,114],[34,69]]]}';
var parsedObjecttree = JSON.parse(Objecttree);
```

For sure this is a json from myself. Replace the json with your data.

Comment: wouldn't you get the same results from removing the surrounding quotes? i.e. var Objecttree = { "type":"Topology",....} and then using that rather than the parsedObjectree?  Assuming, of course, that you TRUST what's in the variable.  If you have the slightest doubt, use JSON.parse as suggested.

Comment: Well that is right for most of the cases sure. But sometimes the json object can contains some signs that harms the code. So this is much safer to use a special function to make sure it always works. I don't know which sign it was, but I had a really really big json file and used it without JSON.parse and it did not work.